# Performing raster cleanup in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects

I am working on Raster cleanup tool and using below but is the output **rectangle** or **block**?

http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriArcScan/IConnectedCells_LocateByDiagonalOfEnvelope.htm

```
Private Sub LocateByDiag()

    Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
    Dim pConCell As IConnectedCells
    Dim pFoundBlock As INotifySelectionBlock

    Set pConCell = Application.FindExtensionByName("ESRI ArcScan Tools")
    Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument
    Set pFoundBlock = New FoundBlock

    pConCell.LocateByDiagonalOfEnvelope 100, True, True, True, pMxDoc.ActiveView.Extent, pFoundBlock, Nothing, Nothing

End Sub
```

Place the following code into a class and name it FoundBlock
Implements INotifySelectionBlock

```
Private Sub INotifySelectionBlock_SelectionBlock(rectangle As tagRECT, ByVal block As Variant, ByVal cancel As ITrackCancel)
    Debug.Print "Found block"
End Sub
```